# How to enable remote connections in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I tried all these ways below to let users communicate with sqls server through the web site but the problem still stands and user is not able to communicate with SQL SERVER

TCP/IP is Enable
http://s3.picofile.com/file/8191899434/TCPIP.png

TCP Port = 1433
http://s6.picofile.com/file/8191899418/TCP_PORT.png

SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER):State = Running and Start Mode = Automatic

SQL Server Browsing: State = Running and Start Mode = Automatic

Server authentication:
SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode

Connections:
Allow remote connections to this server is checked

Comment: Do you need to allow users to connect that server trough internet? Not sure what you mean with "trough the web site"

Comment: what makes you think remote connections is the problem?  Please specify your error message first.

Comment: @Claudio Redi I mean trough the online user interface

Comment: You also need check the firewall settings. Some ISPs even block sql server port completely and you have to change port no to connect it from outside.

Comment: @Tim3880 firewall  is off

Comment: Is the server (not the sql server, the machine) accesible from internet? If the answer is yet, may be possible that a firewall is blocking that port

Comment: @Greg I get no error

Comment: There has to be an error somewhere, please search again.  If you are NOT getting an error, then what makes you think there is a problem?

Comment: @ Greg I transferred project to a VPS that runs Win2008 R2 and set all setting for IIS7. The Project runs and I can see the HTML pages but the problem begins when in Login page or Register Page has no connection to SQL Server and nothing happened.